# What is meant: "Hash.new takes a default value for the hash, which is the value of the hash for a nonexistent key"

Tags: ruby, dictionary, hash

I'm currently going through the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl

Not understanding the meaning of this statement found in [section 4.4.1](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#sec-constructors):

> Hashes, in contrast, are different. While the array constructor
>   Array.new takes an initial value for the array, Hash.new takes a
>   default value for the hash, which is the value of the hash for a
>   nonexistent key:

Could someone help explain what is meant by this? I don't understand what the author is trying to get at regarding how hashes differ from arrays in the context of this section of the book

Comment: If you do not get what that passage says, then perhaps you should ask this on the English site.

Comment: @sawa maybe that was a little harsh?

Comment: Thanks to both respondents, I get it now :)

Answer (score 2):

You can always try out the code in `irb` or `rails console` to find out what they mean.

```
Array.new
# => []

Array.new(7)
# => [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]

h1 = Hash.new
h1['abc']
# => nil

h2 = Hash.new(7)
h2['abc']
# => 7
```

Comment: What's happening with your second example there?

Comment: The argument given to Hash.new defines a default value for any otherwise undefined key in that hash. It can be useful to initialize values to 0 for example, so that every time you see something you can do hash["key"] += 1. Or to initialize them all to an array so you can do hash["key"] << "value". That way, when you're adding to the value for the first time, the hash has a context to start adding from.

Comment: hash["key"] << "value" this will not work

```hash = Hash.new {Array.new} # setup a new array for each key
=> {}
hash[:a] << 'something'
=> ["something"]
a[:a]
=> []```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays and hashes both have a constructor method that takes a value. What this value is used for is different between the two.

For arrays, the value is used to initialize the array (example taken from mentioned tutorial):

```
a = Array.new([1, 3, 2])
# `a` is equal to [1, 3, 2]
```

Unlike arrays, the `new` constructor for hashes doesn't use its passed arguments to initialize the hash. So, for example, typing `h = Hash.new('a', 1)` ***does not*** initialize the hash with a `(key, value)` pair of `a` and `1`:

```
h = Hash.new('a', 1) # NO. Does not give you { 'a' => 1 }!
```

Instead, passing a value to `Hash.new` causes the hash to use that value as a default when a non-existent key is passed. Normally, hashes return `nil` for non-existent keys, but by passing a default value, you can have hashes return the default in those cases:

```
nilHash = { 'x' => 5 }
nilHash['x']   # Return 5, because the key 'x' exists in nilHash
nilHash['foo'] # Returns nil, because there is no key 'foo' in nilHash

defaultHash = Hash.new(100)
defaultHash['x'] = 5
defaultHash['x'] # Return 5, because the key 'x' exists in defaultHash 

defaultHash['foo'] 
# Returns 100 instead of nil, because you passed 100
# as the default value for non-existent keys for this hash
```

Answer (score 2):

Begin by reading the docs for the *class method* [Hash#new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-new).  You will see there are three forms:

```
new → new_hash
new(obj) → new_hash
new {|hash, key| block } → new_hash
```

**Creating an Empty Hash**

The first form is used to create an empty hash:

```
h = Hash.new #=> {}
```

which is more commonly written:

```
h = {}       #=> {}
```

The other two ways of creating a hash with `Hash#new` establish a default value for a key/value pair when the hash does not already contain the key.

**`Hash.new` with an argument**

You can create a hash with a default value in one of two ways:

```
Hash.new(<default value>)
```

or

```
h = Hash.new # or h = {}
h.default = <default value>
```

Suppose the default value for the hash were 4; that is:

```
h = Hash.new(4) #=> {}

h[:pop] = 7     #=> 7
h[:pop] += 1    #=> 8
h[:pop]         #=> 8
h               #=> {:pop=>8}
h[:chips]       #=> 4
h               #=> {:pop=>8}
h[:chips] += 1  #=> 5
h               #=> {:pop=>8, :chips=>5}
h[:chips]       #=> 5
```

Notice that the default value does not affect the value of `:pop`.  That's because it was created with an assignment:

```
h[:pop] = 7
```

`h[:chips]` by itself merely returns the default value (4); it does **not** add the key/value pair `:chips=>4` to the hash!  I repeat: it does **not** add the key/value pair to the hash.  That's important!

```
h[:chips] += 1
```

is shorthand for:

```
h[:chips] = h[:chips] + 1
```

Since the hash `h` does not have a key `:chips` when `h[:chips]` on the right side of the equals sign is evaluated, it returns the default value of 4, then 1 is added to make it 5 and that value is assigned to `h[:chips]`, which adds the key value pair `:chips=>5` to the hash, as seen in following line.  The last line merely reports the value for the existing key `:chips`.

So why would you want to establish a default value? I would venture that the main reason is to be able to initialize it with zero, so you can use:

```
h[k] += 1
```

instead of

```
k[k] = (h.key?(k)) ? h[k] + 1 : 1
```

or the trick:

```
h[k] = (h[k] ||= 0) + 1
```

(which only works when hash values are intended to be non-nil).  Incidentally, `key?` is aka `has_key?`.

Can we make the default a string instead?  Of course:

```
h = Hash.new('magpie')

h[:bluebird]                #=> "magpie"
h                           #=> {}
h[:bluebird] = h[:bluebird] #=> "magpie"
h                           #=> {:bluebird=>"magpie"}
h[:redbird]  = h[:redbird]  #=> "magpie"
h                           #=> {:bluebird=>"magpie", :redbird=>"magpie"}
h[:bluebird] << "jay"       #=> "magpiejay"
h                           #=> {:bluebird=>"magpiejay", :redbird=>"magpiejay"}
```

You may be scratching your head over the last line: why did `h[:bluebird] << "jay"` cause `h[:redbird]` to change??  Perhaps this will explain what's going on here:

```
h[:robin]              #=> "magpiejay"
h[:robin].object_id    #=> 2156227520
h[:bluebird].object_id #=> 2156227520
h[:redbird].object_id  #=> 2156227520
```

`h[:robin]` merely returns the default value, which we see has been changed from "magpie" to "magpiejay".  Now look at the `object_id`'s for the default value and for the values associated with the keys `:bluebird` and `:redbird`.  As you see, all values are the same object, so if we change one, we change all the the others, including the default value.  It is now evident why `h[:bluebird] << "jay"` changed the default value.

We can clarify this further by adding a stately eagle:

```
h[:eagle]               #=> "magpiejay"
h[:eagle] += "starling" #=> "magpiejaystarling"
h[:eagle].object_id     #=> 2157098780
h #=> {:bluebird=>"magpiejay", :redbird=>"magpiejay", :eagle=>"magpiejaystarling"}
```

Because

```
h[:eagle] += "starling" #=> "magpiejaystarling"
```

is equivalent to:

```
h[:eagle] = h[:eagle] + "starling"
```

we have created a new object on the right side of the equals sign and assigned it to `h[:eagle]`.  That's why the values for the keys `:bluebird` and `:redbird` are unaffected and `h[:eagle]` has a different `object_id`.

We have the similar problems if we write: `Hash.new([])` or `Hash.new({})`.  If there are ever reasons to use those defaults, I'm not aware of them.  It certainly can be very useful for the default value to be an empty string, array or hash, but for that you need the third form of `Hash.new`, which takes a block.

**`Hash.new` with a block**

We now consider the third and final version of `Hash#new`, which takes a block, like so:

```
Hash.new { |h,k| ??? }
```

You may be expecting this to be devilishly complex and subtle, certainly much harder to grasp than the other two forms of the method.  If so, you'd be wrong.  It's actually quite simple, if you think of it as looking like this:

```
Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = ??? }
```

In other words, Ruby is saying to you, "The hash `h` doesn't have the key `k`.  What would you like it's value to be? Now consider the following:

```
h7 = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=7 }
hs = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]='cat' }
ha = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] }
hh = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]={} }

h7[:a] += 3            #=> 10
hs[:b] << 'nip'        #=> "catnip"
ha[:c] << 4 << 6       #=> [4, 6]
ha[:d] << 7            #=> [7]
ha                     #=> {:c=>[4, 6], :d=>[7]}
hh[:k].merge({b: 4})   #=> {:b=>4}
hh                     #=> {}
hh[:k].merge!({b: 4} ) #=> {:b=>4}
hh                     #=> {:k=>{:b=>4}}
```

Notice that you cannot write `ha = Hash.new { |h,k| [] }` (or equivalently, `ha = Hash.new { [] }`) and expect `h[k] => []` to be added to the hash.  You can do whatever you like within the block; you are neither required nor limited to specifying a value for the key.  In effect, within the block Ruby is actually saying, "A key that is not in the hash has been referenced without a value.  I'm giving you that reference and also a reference to the hash.  That will allow you to add that key with a value to the hash, if that's what you want to do, but what you do in this block is entirely your business."

The default values for the hashes `h7`, `hs`, `ha` and `hh` are respectively the number 7 (though it would be easier to simply enter 7 as An argument), an empty string, an empty array or an empty hash.  Probably the last two are the most common use of `Hash#new` with a block, as in:

```
array = [[:a, 1], [:b, 3], [:a, 4], [:b, 6]]
array.each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}) { |(k,v),h| h[k] << v }
  #=> {:a=>[1, 4], :b=>[3, 6]}
```

That's really about all there is to the last form of `Hash#new`.